# jQuery tablesorter month name locale

Tags: jquery, locale, tablesorter

Using the  [jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://www.tablesorter.com/) . I wonder how could I make it work with dates in the full format:

> "Jan 21, 2009 16:00"

Problem is that when that date (a string) has been localized with user current locale

> "gen 21, 2009 16:00"

Do I have to write a custom sorter for each locale?

Thanks.

```
<table id="orders" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Da</th>
            <th>Al</th>
            <th class="right">Camere</th>
            <th class="right">Spesa dell'ordine</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>gen 21, 2009 22:00</td>
        <td>gen 22, 2009 22:00</td>
        <td class="right">1</td>
        <td class="right">30.00€</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to have tablesorter automatically detect the localized columns as dates , or are you happy to specify that the column is a date column, and just have tablesorter do the sorting?

Comment: Please include part of the html>table

Comment: Tablesorter recognize the english string as Date flawless; of course I would like that happens even for other locale but I would need that just work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Tablesorter plugin will detect that "gen 21, 2009' is a date column. It will then pass it to the javascript Date constructor to parse it; that might be the step that fails. (I don't know if the constructor accepts localized strings; you can test that by running this:

```
new Date("gen 21, 2009 16:00").getTime();
```

If it returns "NaN" (as it does on my en-US firefox), then you'll need a custom parser. If it returns 1232514000000 then you don't need to do anything.

Tablesorter will detect a column as "US long date" if it matches this regular expression:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{3,10}\.? [0-9]{1,2}, ([0-9]{4}|'?[0-9]{2}) (([0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s(AM|PM)))$/
```

a.k.a:

- 3 - 10 alphabetic characters (month)
- an optional period
- a space
- 1 - 2 digits (day)
- comma, then space
- 4-digit year, or apostrophe followed by 2-digit year
- optional 24 hour time, or 12-hour time followed by uppercase AM or PM.